# Cannot assign to read only property<fieldName> of object '#<Object>'

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd

I am facing a issue while dealing with API data. Basically I have a model where I map through all the data from API and create a title and it's Input field so that I can change it. Problem is When I get data from API and I try to change some nested property [I did not even submit the problem occurs `OnChange`] in object The application crashes and show's me this error:

[image]

But when I copy the API data and paste it in a variable and then pass it to my MODAL everything works fine.

Here is demo link of my project:
https://playcode.io/1801590

Using Static Data: I can change object and normal field and nested arrays
Using API: I can change normal field but not object or nested arrays.

I tried to copy API data to an state or variable and pass it but It gave me same error.
I am expecting it to behave same for static data and API data